# Unused output of a flyback transformer

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, flyback

I have a flyback transformer.  It has 2 outputs. I'm going to use one of them on a flyback converter.

Should I leave the second output of the transformer unconnected or connect a load to it?

Comment: It's usually a good idea to connect one end of any unused secondary somewhere, typically GND.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *should I left the second output of the transformer empty or connect a
> load to it?*

If it's no problem, leave it open circuit or, if it's the same voltage as the other secondary, you should be able to parallel them up to reduce \$I^2R\$ losses in the secondary.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that depends on what the second output is for. There aren't two equal transformer in the world.

Often the second winding is for auxiliary bias but it could be a reset winding or a second output. Unless you know how it's wound you can't say for sure.

In doubt keep it open